# Show that for any $\varepsilon >0$ there exists a set $B \subset \Bbb R^n$ such that $A \subset B$ and $m^\ast(B) \le m^\ast(A) + \varepsilon.$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $A \subset \Bbb R^n$. Show that for any $\varepsilon >0$ there exists a set $B \subset \Bbb R^n$ such that $A \subset B$ and $$m^\ast(B) \le m^\ast(A) + \varepsilon.$$

My attempt was to let $\{I_k\}$ be a cover for $A$. Now since $$m^\ast(A) =\inf \{\sum_{I \in I_k} \ell(I) : \text{ $I_k$ covers $A$ \}}$$

and from the definition of infimum for any $\sum_{I \in I_k} \ell(I) $ we have $$m^\ast(A) \le \sum_{I \in I_k} \ell(I) +\varepsilon.$$

Now let $B = \bigcup_{k} I_k \implies A \subset B$ and we get $$m^\ast(B) = m^\ast\left(\bigcup_{k} I_k \right) \le \sum_{I \in I_k} m^\ast(I) = \sum_{I \in I_k} \ell(I) $$

But I don’t have anything to approximate this further... If anything I would get that $$m^\ast(A) - \varepsilon \le \sum_{I \in I_k} \ell(I) $$ but this doesn’t help. What should I do here?

Comment: Is $l(I)$ the length of an Interval?

Comment: Yes indeed it is.

Comment: But you are in $n$-dimensional space, so how is this meant? The volume of a cartesian product of intervals?

Comment: Yes it’s basically a ”volume” in this case. $\ell(I) = \prod_{i=1}^n (b_i - a_i).$

Comment: If you have no conditions on $B$, you can take $B=A$...

Comment: It seems that $\supset$ means $B\neq A$

Comment: Yes $B \ne A$...

Comment: Maybe you should add that in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just notice that this definition $m^\ast(A) =\inf \{\sum_{I \in I_k} \ell(I) : \text{ $I_k$ covers $A$ \}}$ gives you that for all $\varepsilon>0$ you have a cover of $A$, name it $(I_k)$, such that $\sum_1^{+\infty}l(I_k) \leq m^*(A)+\varepsilon$ and not $m^\ast(A) \le \sum_1^{+\infty} \ell(I_k) +\varepsilon$. Thus your remarks help you to conclude.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a bit which has less volume than $\epsilon$:

Assume that $A\neq \mathbb{R}^n$, otherwise there may be some problems about $\infty$. So basically $m^*(A)=\operatorname{vol}(A)$.

Now let's take any set $C\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ with $C\cap A = \emptyset$ and $m^*(C) < \epsilon$. This can be e.g. the square $\prod_i[a_i,a_i+(\epsilon/2)^{1/n}]$ for some $a_i\in\mathbb{R}$, which has volume $\varepsilon/2$.

Take $B=A\cup C$ and you get
$$
m^*(B) = m^*(A)+m^*(C) < m^*(A)+\epsilon
$$
You can split the addition because $A\cap C = \emptyset$.

You just have to ensure that such a $C$ exists, but as $A\neq \mathbb{R}^n$ there should always be such a $C\subset \mathbb{R}^n\setminus A$.

Comment: Why not a singleton for $C$?

Comment: That's also possible. But then the volume of $C$ is 0. I assumed that the volumes of $A$ and $B$ shouldn't be equal